# Scala testing - not found: type RunWith

Tags: eclipse, scala, junit, sbt

I am doing the Scala course from Coursera.

Within the file containing the unit tests, I am getting the following error:

```
not found: type RunWith
```

The top of the file looks like this:

```
package funsets   
import org.scalatest.FunSuite 
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class FunSetSuite extends FunSuite {
```

The error appears at the line containing @RunWith

Comment: Seems like you are just missing an import: `import org.junit.runner.RunWith`

Comment: I added that. Now it doesn't recognize the `junit` import: `object junit is not a member of package org`. How can I add the JUnit library to the project?

Comment: See if [this link](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-junit-testing-with-scala) will help you.

Comment: I tried following the instructions in the link but when I run `sbt eclipse` I am getting many errors such as: `[error] (assignment/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;4.0.0: not found`

Comment: Make sure you have this file project/plugins.sbt with: addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")